# Identifying the polygon to delete

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I would like to know how I can give (and retrieve) an ID to a polygon in leaflet(.draw). I need this because I want to be able to tell the database which polygon to delete/edit.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

In my database I save a polygon_ID and the coordinates for a polygon. This is the code where I save a polygon: (This is trigered when I finish drawing the polygon)

```js
map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

  if (type == "polygon") {

    var polygon = {};
    polygon['geometry'] = {};
    polygon['geometry']['type'] = "Polygon";

    var coordinates = [];
    latlngs = layer.getLatLngs();
    for (var i = 0; i < latlngs.length; i++) {

      coordinates.push([latlngs[i].lat, latlngs[i].lng])

    }

    polygon['geometry']['coordinates'] = [coordinates];

    coordinates = JSON.stringify(coordinates);

    //console.log(coordinates);

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        //alert("Sent!");
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "inc/send.php?a=add&t=polygon&c=" + coordinates, true);
    xhttp.send();

  }

  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

});
```

This is my send.php:

```html
if(isset($_GET['c']) && isset($_GET['t']) && isset($_GET['a'])){

  $coordinates = $_GET['c'];
  $type   = $_GET['t'];
  $action   = $_GET['a'];

  if($type == "polygon" && $action == "add"){

    $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO polygons (coordinates) VALUES (:coordinates)');
    $sth->bindParam(':coordinates', $coordinates);
    $sth->execute();

  }

} else {



}
```

This is how I load in my polygons:

```html
$polygonsth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM polygons");
$polygonsth->execute();
$polygonresult = $polygonsth->fetchAll();

...

foreach ($polygonresult as $row) {
 
echo "L.polygon(" . $row['coordinates'] . ")
 .addTo(drawnItems);
 //console.log(pol.options.id);
";

}
```

I really hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Depends on in what format you store your polygons and we can't make that up out of your very short question. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough. In my database I store all the lattitude and longitude positions of polygon's handles, and I have on ID for each polygon. My question is how I can link the leaflet and the mysql ID together so I can tell the database what polygon to delete. I use AJAX to execute the query. Maybe you could help me now?

Comment: Still depends on how you initialize your polygons and the way you add them to the map. Could you please edit your question and add the info you put in your comment to it and include the relevant code on how you add the polygons to your map? Individual polygons? FeatureLayer? GeoJSON? Too many variables to give a good answer

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Yes, perfect. I'll have a go at an answer later on today when i have some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the ID to your polygon instance as an option parameter:

```
foreach ($polygonresult as $row) {

    echo "L.polygon(" . $row['coordinates'] . ", { id: " . $row['id'] . "}).addTo(drawnItems);";

}
```

Now when you delete polygons from your `drawnItems` layer, catch and handle the `draw:deleted` event. It returns a `L.LayerGroup` which you can iterate to handle the deleted polygons:

```
map.on('draw:deleted', function (e) {

    var layers = e.layers;

    layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                //alert("Deleted!");
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "inc/send.php?a=delete&t=polygon&i=" + layer.options.id, true);
        xhttp.send();

    });

});
```

Now on the serverside, catch the `GET` parameter for `i` and delete the polygon from the database:

```
if(isset($_GET['i']) && isset($_GET['t']) && isset($_GET['a'])){

    $id = $_GET['i'];
    $type = $_GET['t'];
    $action = $_GET['a'];

    if ($type == "polygon" && $action == "delete") {

        $sth = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM polygons WHERE id = :id');
        $sth->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $sth->execute();

    }

}
```

That's it. Mind you, disclaimer: i am unable to test it so i had to freehand it and it's been a long time since i've done PHP. But as far as i know, it should be ok. Good luck!

Comment: No thanks, you're always welcome, this is what SO is meant for :) I'de like to warn you tho, i don't know if this is going to be your actual implementation it's rather insecure. You'll really need some input validation and authentication on the serverside because like this it can easily be abused. Simply visiting the url `inc/send.php?a=delete&t=polygon&i=(guess some id's)` would potentially delete any polygon. A malicious user would have a field day

Comment: I know, I'm putting it in a CMS (with secure login of course) where only certain users will have the right to edit/delete polygons/polylines/etc.